# Substitution / Elimination competition

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I am trying the hypothetical synthesis below, but I didn't get the product I was expecting. Instead, the reaction formed mostly styrene, in >80% yield (elimination product of the bromide)

[image]

The synthesis of an analogous product with one less carbon in the bromide (benzylic bromide) is described in the literature and I thought it would work with this one since they only differ by a carbon. Any thoughts on how I could overcome this selectivity problem?

I thought about using a milder base, but I don't think the problem here is actually the base I use, cause they will all form the enolate, the problem is the enolate abstracting the benzylic proton from the bromide and generating styrene + butyrolactone.

Comment: What was the procedure? Preform the enolate then add the bromide? Or add the base to the mixture of lactone and bromide?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention... The enolate was formed first and then the bromide was added.

Comment: It is a bit too easy to form the styrene this way. Could you use phenacyl bromide instead then do a Clemmensen to get the desired product? Or react the enolate with styrene oxide and hydrogenate.

Comment: Clemmensen would not reduce the lactone, right?

Comment: Should not do so. Could always reduce it stepwise with sodium borohydride the ionic hydrogenation.